# What is the probablity that the sum of two dice is 4 or 6?

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, dice

> What is the probablity that the sum of two dice is 4 or 6?

The explanation I found is as follows:
Total number of outcomes $6 \times6 = 36$
Number of outcomes where the event occurs: $1+3, 2+2, 3+1, 1+5, 2+4, 3+3, 4+2$ and $5+1$ (Total $ 8$)

The probability that the event occurs is $8/36$ or $2/9$

My doubt is why $1+3$ and $3+1$ are considered as separate outcomes. Isn't it the same as the dices are identical and we cannot really find out which dice had which number on it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the term _sample space_?

Comment: If you want to you can regard the events $(3,1)$ and $(1,3)$ as the same, let's call it $\{1,3\}$.  But if you do that then you have to assign it twice the probability that you assign to, say, $\{2,2\}$.

Comment: Are you thinking of a regular blank-free set of dominoes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability and dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1966075/probability-and-dice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In developing an understanding of the sample space, you should think of the two dice as being distinct.  Yes, in principle, the two dice may be indistinguishable.  However, from the point of view of probability theory, the behaviour of each die is described by a different random variable.  Hence the two dice are not, really, indistinguishable.  Maybe one of them is blue and the other red, or one is rolled before the other, or one has a cute little smiley face drawn in place of the $3$.

From this point of view, the outcome $1+3$ represent rolling a $1$ and then a $3$, while the outcome $3+1$ represents rolling a $3$ and then a $1$.  In terms of the ultimate nature of the *events* being modeled, these two outcomes are the same (both yield a $4$), but as *outcomes* (or *elementary events*) in the underlying sample space, they are distinct.  To make this more concrete, imagine that the dice are rolled one after the other, and suppose that they are colored differently.  For example, if one of the dice is blue and the other red, then the sample space looks like

$$ \begin{array}{c|cccccc}
 & \color{red}{1} 
 & \color{red}{2} 
 & \color{red}{3} 
 & \color{red}{4} 
 & \color{red}{5}
 & \color{red}{6} \\\hline
\color{blue}{1}
 & (\color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{1})
 & (\color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{2})
 & (\color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{3})
 & (\color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{4})
 & (\color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{5})
 & (\color{blue}{1}, \color{red}{6}) \\
\color{blue}{2}
 & (\color{blue}{2}, \color{red}{1})
 & (\color{blue}{2}, \color{red}{2})
 & (\color{blue}{2}, \color{red}{3})
 & (\color{blue}{2}, \color{red}{4})
 & (\color{blue}{2}, \color{red}{5})
 & (\color{blue}{2}, \color{red}{6}) \\
\color{blue}{3}
 & (\color{blue}{3}, \color{red}{1})
 & (\color{blue}{3}, \color{red}{2})
 & (\color{blue}{3}, \color{red}{3})
 & (\color{blue}{3}, \color{red}{4})
 & (\color{blue}{3}, \color{red}{5})
 & (\color{blue}{3}, \color{red}{6}) \\
\color{blue}{4}
 & (\color{blue}{4}, \color{red}{1})
 & (\color{blue}{4}, \color{red}{2})
 & (\color{blue}{4}, \color{red}{3})
 & (\color{blue}{4}, \color{red}{4})
 & (\color{blue}{4}, \color{red}{5})
 & (\color{blue}{4}, \color{red}{6}) \\
\color{blue}{5}
 & (\color{blue}{5}, \color{red}{1})
 & (\color{blue}{5}, \color{red}{2})
 & (\color{blue}{5}, \color{red}{3})
 & (\color{blue}{5}, \color{red}{4})
 & (\color{blue}{5}, \color{red}{5})
 & (\color{blue}{5}, \color{red}{6}) \\
\color{blue}{6}
 & (\color{blue}{6}, \color{red}{1})
 & (\color{blue}{6}, \color{red}{2})
 & (\color{blue}{6}, \color{red}{3})
 & (\color{blue}{6}, \color{red}{4})
 & (\color{blue}{6}, \color{red}{5})
 & (\color{blue}{6}, \color{red}{6}) \\
\end{array}
$$
This sample space gives all of the possible outcomes, of which there are $36$.  Moreover, and of crucial importance, is that every one of these outcomes is **equally likely**.  Showing that all of these outcomes are equally likely requires a little bit of work, but the essential ideas are that

- each die is modeled by a uniform variable on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$,
  which means that the probability of rolling any particular number on either die is $1/6$, and
- the two die rolls are *independent*, which means (more or less) that the number rolled on one of the two dice does not depend on the result of the other.

These two observations are sufficient to show that all $36$ outcomes are equally probable.

However, we are only interested in the *event* which describes a sum of either $4$ or $6$.  Replacing the specific die rolls with the corresponding sums in the table above gives
$$ \begin{array}{c|cccccc}
 & \color{red}{1} 
 & \color{red}{2} 
 & \color{red}{3} 
 & \color{red}{4} 
 & \color{red}{5}
 & \color{red}{6} \\\hline
\color{blue}{1}
 & 2 & 3 & \boxed{4} & 5 & \boxed{6} & 7 \\
\color{blue}{2}
 & 3 & \boxed{4} & 5 & \boxed{6} & 7 & 8 \\
\color{blue}{3}
 & \boxed{4} & 5 & \boxed{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\color{blue}{4}
 & 5 & \boxed{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\color{blue}{5}
 & \boxed{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
\color{blue}{6}
 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
\end{array}
$$
From this presentation, it can be seen that there are $8$ "good" outcomes (i.e. there are $8$ elementary events giving a sum of either $4$ or $6$), out of a total of $36$ equiprobable outcomes.  Thus
$$ P(\text{two dice sum to either $4$ or $6$})
= \frac{8}{36} = \frac{2}{9}. $$

Comment: Excellent answer. I was sadly surprised to discover that I could not find any answer on Math SE related to dice that pinpointed this crucial basic concept underlying basic probability (where there are finitely many possible outcomes). The best I could find was the one that I voted to close the question as duplicate of, but that's nowhere as comprehensive as yours. Thanks for taking the effort to write this up!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to visualize the sample space:
\begin{array}{c|llllll}
+ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & \color{blue}{4} & 5 & \color{blue}{6} & 7\\
2 & 3 & \color{blue}{4} & 5 & \color{blue}{6} & 7 & 8\\
3 & \color{blue}{4} & 5 & \color{blue}{6} & 7 & 8 & 9\\
4 & 5 & \color{blue}{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
5 & \color{blue}{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10& 11\\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10& 11 & 12\\
\end{array}
In blue we have the favourable outcomes.  Hence, the probability of getting a sum of $4$ or $6$ is $8/36$, or $2/9$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to think of this question.

Take a coin. There are two sides, Heads and Tails. With your logic then HT and TH is the same. Does that mean the probability of getting one head and one tail is $\frac{1}{4}$? No, it's $\frac{1}{2}$ because you can arrange the ways.

-FruDe

Comment: If you are tossing a single coin, the order does matter. However, if you tossing two identical coins, then HT and TH are the same outcomes I believe

Answer (score 0):

Write down $\Omega$

$\Omega=\{(1;1),(1;2),...,(6;6)\}$

And count the favourable pairs...